# In Microsoft Word, why does the font automatically change to Yu Mincho every time I switch to Japanese input?

Tags: fonts, ms-word, default, typography

I want uniformity across Western and Asian fonts because I have to type multilingual documents.

This happens in other Office programs as well:
1. In PowerPoint, it automatically switches to Yu Gothic Light.
2. In Excel, it's Microsoft Yahei, but it displays as Calibri.

This doesn't happen when I'm typing Japanese in other applications, including my web browser, and even Notepad, so I'm certain it's an Office issue.

I've searched all over the internet for solutions and none of them have solved the problem.

Comment: This happens in OneNote too, and it is infuriating. You're tying along in Calibri, you switch to Japanese to type a word or two and the system switches you to a different font (Yu Gothic in my case). Then you switch back to English and you're now still in Yu Gothic, which looks totally different from Calibri, even though you never asked for the font to be changed!

Answer (score 0):

You might be running into an issue where the Office Suite is defaulting. This might be in the "normal" template or just in the document itself. Do either of these work for you?

Change or set default font: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-or-set-the-default-font-20f72414-2c42-4b53-9654-d07a92b9294a

Configure or turn off automatic text formatting (AutoFormat): https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-or-turn-off-automatic-text-formatting-AutoFormat-195c72fc-5e3f-43d5-a0c3-bf3606e2e58e?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem for me (June 2020, MSWord for Mac 16.30):

1. Open Styles pane, and under “Apply a Style” open the drop-down for
   “Normal” and click “Modify style”;
2. In the next dialog, open drop-down next to “Format” at lower left, and select “Font”
3. In the next dialog, Select desired Asian and Latin fonts and click “OK”
4. Back now in the first dialog, Check “Add to template” box and click "OK"
5. Close and reopen the document to re-load the template.